# Calling several WinAPI functions results in around 30 errors

Tags: c++, c, winapi

For some reason, I try to call AdjustWindowRect, or GetClientRect, and the parameters I provide are fine. I get around 30 errors, none of which relate to the call to the WinAPI function.

What could cause such a thing?

Thanks

For example:

The following code:

```
   case WM_GETMINMAXINFO:
          {
              LPMINMAXINFO p_info = (LPMINMAXINFO)lParam;
              RECT rc = {0,0,d->w,d->h};
              DWORD dwStyle = GetWindowLongPtr( hWnd, GWL_STYLE ) ;
              AdjustWindowRect(&rc,dwStyle,FALSE);
              int total_border_width = 2 * GetSystemMetrics( SM_CXFRAME ) + 4;
              int total_border_height = 2 * GetSystemMetrics( SM_CYFRAME ) + 
                 GetSystemMetrics( SM_CYCAPTION ) - GetSystemMetrics( SM_CYBORDER ) + 5;
              POINT min,max;

              min.x = d->min_w > 0 ? d->min_w + total_border_width : p_info->ptMinTrackSize.x;
              min.y = d->min_h > 0 ? d->min_h + total_border_height : p_info->ptMinTrackSize.y;
              max.x = d->max_w > 0 ? d->max_w + total_border_width : p_info->ptMaxTrackSize.x;
              max.y = d->max_h > 0 ? d->max_h + total_border_height : p_info->ptMaxTrackSize.y;

              p_info->ptMinTrackSize = min;
              p_info->ptMaxTrackSize = max;
          }
```

Produces:

```
Error   6   error C2065: 'max' : undeclared identifier  c:\Users\Josh\Documents\AL51\src\win\wwindow.c  844
Error   13  error C2065: 'max' : undeclared identifier  c:\Users\Josh\Documents\AL51\src\win\wwindow.c  848
Error   16  error C2065: 'max' : undeclared identifier  c:\Users\Josh\Documents\AL51\src\win\wwindow.c  849
Error   21  error C2065: 'max' : undeclared identifier  c:\Users\Josh\Documents\AL51\src\win\wwindow.c  852
Error   5   error C2065: 'min' : undeclared identifier  c:\Users\Josh\Documents\AL51\src\win\wwindow.c  844
Error   7   error C2065: 'min' : undeclared identifier  c:\Users\Josh\Documents\AL51\src\win\wwindow.c  846
Error   10  error C2065: 'min' : undeclared identifier  c:\Users\Josh\Documents\AL51\src\win\wwindow.c  847
Error   19  error C2065: 'min' : undeclared identifier  c:\Users\Josh\Documents\AL51\src\win\wwindow.c  851
Error   12  error C2065: 'total_border_height' : undeclared identifier  c:\Users\Josh\Documents\AL51\src\win\wwindow.c  847
Error   18  error C2065: 'total_border_height' : undeclared identifier  c:\Users\Josh\Documents\AL51\src\win\wwindow.c  849
Error   9   error C2065: 'total_border_width' : undeclared identifier   c:\Users\Josh\Documents\AL51\src\win\wwindow.c  846
Error   15  error C2065: 'total_border_width' : undeclared identifier   c:\Users\Josh\Documents\AL51\src\win\wwindow.c  848
Error   1   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'   c:\Users\Josh\Documents\AL51\src\win\wwindow.c  841
Error   2   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'   c:\Users\Josh\Documents\AL51\src\win\wwindow.c  842
Error   4   error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'min' c:\Users\Josh\Documents\AL51\src\win\wwindow.c  844
Error   8   error C2224: left of '.x' must have struct/union type   c:\Users\Josh\Documents\AL51\src\win\wwindow.c  846
Error   14  error C2224: left of '.x' must have struct/union type   c:\Users\Josh\Documents\AL51\src\win\wwindow.c  848
Error   11  error C2224: left of '.y' must have struct/union type   c:\Users\Josh\Documents\AL51\src\win\wwindow.c  847
Error   17  error C2224: left of '.y' must have struct/union type   c:\Users\Josh\Documents\AL51\src\win\wwindow.c  849
Error   3   error C2275: 'POINT' : illegal use of this type as an expression    c:\Users\Josh\Documents\AL51\src\win\wwindow.c  844
Error   20  error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'POINT' c:\Users\Josh\Documents\AL51\src\win\wwindow.c  851
Error   22  error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'POINT' c:\Users\Josh\Documents\AL51\src\win\wwindow.c  852
```

Comment: Is this code part of a .c file or .cpp?

Comment: Then you need to move all your variable declarations to the top of the block as James McNellis has indicated below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual C++ only supports C90 (not C99), so when compiling a C program, you must place all variable declarations at the top of the block, before any statements.

The declarations of `min`, `max`, `total_border_height` and `total_border_width` all come after at least one statement in the block.

Comment: Nope, builds like a charm with a simple removal of AdjustRect or any other winapi function, I also renamed min and max, no luck.